# Search by close match

Tags: search

I'm looking for a way to get search results, even if people make typos, so apple as a result when looking for aple. Not fuzzy search, but some implementation of, for example, a Levenshtein function. I know I could go the Algolia way and that there's even a [plugin](http://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/searchplus) for that, but before I pay Algolia for it, I would like to know:

- Is there an easy/quick way to do this without using an external service?
- If so, would you be willing to share your thoughts on the subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there an easy/quick way to do this without using an external service?

Nothing easy I can think of.

For Craft 2 (which only supports MySQL), Craft turns those search queries into a MySQL query that can take advantage of MySQL's Full Text Search indexes on the `craft_searchindex` table, using full text wildcards as necessary for fuzzy searching the beginning and ending of a string.

It looks like the closest thing that MySQL has that might do what you're looking for is [SOUNDEX()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex), but 1) Craft doesn't use that and 2) it doesn't appear that SOUNDEX can be used against full text indexes.

Keep in mind (just like [Search Plus](http://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/searchplus)) any solution you find is only going to affect front-end searches (not in the CP).

You should add a thumbs-up/comment to this feature request if you'd like to see that change: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/833

Comment: I found SOUNDEX() indeed, but that's not cutting it. I will use one of my thumbs up to support the request for more advanced search features.

Comment: I'm sorry to have disappointed you, Paul.

Comment: Never mind, Brad. I'll live.